# ¿Por qué el DRAE afirma que la teología es una ciencia?

Tags: definiciones, dle, ciencia

Entre las múltiples definiciones que proporciona el Diccionario de la Real Academia Española (DRAE) sobre el termino teología, el principal lo describe como "ciencia":

> [**teología**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=9S42XokhcDXX2tkbwMCW)
>
> 1. f. Ciencia que trata de Dios y de sus atributos y perfecciones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No me parece que haya ninguna contradicción, si consideramos la definición de "ciencia":

> [**ciencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9AwuYaT)
>   `Del lat. scientia.`
>
> 1. f. Conjunto de conocimientos obtenidos mediante la observación y el razonamiento, sistemáticamente estructurados y de los que se deducen principios y leyes generales con capacidad predictiva y comprobables experimentalmente.
> 2. f. Saber o erudición. *Tener mucha, o poca, ciencia. Ser un pozo de ciencia. Hombre de ciencia y virtud.*
> 3. f. Habilidad, maestría, conjunto de conocimientos en cualquier cosa. *La ciencia del caco, del palaciego, del hombre vividor.*
> 4. f. pl. Conjunto de conocimientos relativos a las ciencias exactas, físicas, químicas y naturales.

Más allá del respeto que me merece la teología, hasta las "ciencias ocultas" son definidas como tales en la misma entrada:

> **ciencias ocultas**
>
> 1. f. pl. Prácticas y conocimientos misteriosos, como la magia, la alquimia, la astrología, etc., que, desde la antigüedad, pretenden penetrar y dominar los secretos de la naturaleza.